# how does this function expression work?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Function express CANNOT be used before being declared correct?  But is also passed in a keypress function as well.  How is this magic happening?

I am doing a code along and noticed it while I was looking over it.

```
    var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl){


        var setUpEventListeners = function(){
           //CTRLADDITEM is called below
            document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', **ctrlAddItem**);
        document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){

        if(event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){

          **ctrlAddItem();**
        }
    });

        }

var **ctrlAddItem** = function(){



         updateBudget();

               }
       };
 }
 })(budgetController, UIController );
```

Comment: Is **`easy === looooooong`**?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate your issue. It's difficult to tell what "this function" is.

Comment: By the time you actually trigger the event handler it will be declared.

Comment: Look up **IIFE** (**I**mmediately **I**nvoked **F**unction **E**xpression).

Comment: Far too much code, even if you remove the dozens of useless blank lines. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "*but var test = function(){} can only be executed once the code parser reaches that var right?*" Wrong. The function is assigned only when the expression is **executed**, which is long after being parsed (and may never happen).

Answer (score 1):

This is called [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and it's fairly common in Javascript as well as other languages like Go. Here is a simple version...

```
(function() {
   alert('invoked immediately');
})();
```

This code will run immediately. Note: it is **not** invoked before it is defined. It is invoked by the trailing parenthesis, which come directly **after** it is defined. It is the exact same thing as doing this...

```
function doSomething() {

}

doSomething();
```

We have just inlined the function by wrapping it in parenthesis and then called it `()`, instead of calling it by name.

If you assign the result to a variable, it works just as expected, you are assigning the result of the function.

```
// these two are equivalent
var result = (function () {
    return 5;
})();

var result = 5;
```

Now, the value in `result` will equal `5`.

**Why do we use them?**

Most commonly, we use them to isolate the scope of your code to prevent it from polluting the global scope. For example, if this is your application code...

```
function MyApp() {

}
```

You have now polluted the global scope by creating `window.MyApp`. If you use a third party library that also provides a function on the global scope called `MyApp`, it will override yours. To prevent that, we can do...

```
(function(window) {

    function MyApp() {}
    MyApp();

})(window);
```

Now, `MyApp` is not attached to the window and we still have access to the window.

**Further down the rabbit hole**

You must convert your function from a declaration to an expression before you can invoke it immediately. To do this, you wrap it in parenthesis.

This does **NOT work**

```
function (){
   // do something
}()
```

This **DOES** work (thanks to the parenthesis)

```
(function () {

})()
```

You can also use any unary operator instead of parenthesis. **All of these work**

```
~function () {

}()

+function () {

}()

-function () {

}()

void function () {

}()
```

Comment: I think I get where youre coming from.  I did a test in code pen, so basically the IIFE invokes ALL the code inside with the trailing () - so by the time setup event listeners is executed, all the code inside the IIFE has already happened - correct?:

Comment: Yes, that is correct. All of that code runs immediately. Copy and paste my very first example in your javascript console and the alert will fire immediately. You have declared and invoked the function in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did some testing and although I know what an IFFE is, this does not appear to work, why is that? @Charlie Martin:

(function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', martin);
   var martin = function(){alert('invoked immediately')};
})();

Comment: Nevermind I did some testing and found out.  the whole function is run by the time a.init() is called thanks for your help did some testing @Charlie Martin------- var a = (function() {
  function setUp(){
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', martin);
  }
   var martin = function(){alert('invoked immediately')};
  return{init: function(){
    setUp();
    }
  }
  
})();

a.init();

Comment: There is one small problem with your first example and it is that you defined the function `martin` AFTER you passed it to `addEventListener`, so you really passed it `undefined`. This is an issue with hoisting in javascript, which is another can of worms :) Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/dh3drpLy/

Answer (score 0):

What you have is:

```
// Pass ctrlAddItem
document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

// Include closure to ctrlAddItem in function expression
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if(event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13){
        ctrlAddItem();
    }
});

// later...
var ctrlAddItem = function(){ /* whatever */ }
```

So *ctrlAddItem* is declared, and therefore exists with a value of *undefined* before any code is executed. At the point it's used in *addEventListener*, its value is still undefined.

However, before the outer function completes (and before the listeners are called), *ctrlAddItem* is assigned a value. So by the time the listeners are called, it's a (reference to a) function.